# align break one long formula

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I'm using the align environment to create four rows which each contain three formulas. One of them is to long. How do I break this specific formula to two lines?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\textnormal{FFNN eins:} && w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1+13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_1}  \\
\textnormal {FFNN zwei:} && w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*h_2)+(h_2*13) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_2} \\
\textnormal{RNN eins:} && w &= (9*h_1 + h_1^2)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_1} \\
\textnormal {RNN zwei:} && w &= (9*h_1+h_1^2+h_1)+(h_1*h_2+h_2^2+h_2)+(h_2*13) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The middle formula in the last row is to long and makes everything look ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another line to the `align` environment which you don't number:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\textnormal{FFNN eins:} && w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1+13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_1}  \\
\textnormal {FFNN zwei:} && w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*h_2)+(h_2*13) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_2} \\
\textnormal{RNN eins:} && w &= (9*h_1 + h_1^2)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_1} \\
\textnormal {RNN zwei:} && w &= (9*h_1+h_1^2+h_1) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13
\label{eqn:w_rnn_2}\\
&&&\phantom{={}}+(h_1*h_2+h_2^2+h_2)+(h_2*13) \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use an `aligned` environment in that line:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\textnormal{FFNN eins:} && w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1+13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_1}  \\
\textnormal {FFNN zwei:} && w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*h_2)+(h_2*13) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_2} \\
\textnormal{RNN eins:} && w &= (9*h_1 + h_1^2)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_1} \\
\textnormal {RNN zwei:} && w &=
\begin{aligned}[t]&(9*h_1+h_1^2+h_1)\\&+(h_1*h_2+h_2^2+h_2)+(h_2*13)\end{aligned} & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

(Output looks the same)

Answer (score 1):

if `*` is just a normal product I would drop it (aaa) if it is a special product and you need the `*` syntax then you can cramp the space slightly (bbb)

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
aaa
\begin{align}
\shortintertext{FFNN eins:}
w &= (180h_1)+(h_113) & b &= h_1+13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_1}  \\
\shortintertext{FFNN zwei:}
 w &= (180h_1)+(h_1h_2)+(h_213) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_2} \\
\shortintertext{RNN eins:}
w &= (9h_1 + h_1^2)+(h_113) & b &= h_1 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_1} \\
\shortintertext{RNN zwei:}
 w &= (9h_1+h_1^2+h_1)+(h_1h_2+h_2^2+h_2)+(h_213) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_2}
\end{align}

bbb{\medmuskip=2mu
\begin{align}
\shortintertext{FFNN eins:}
w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1+13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_1}  \\
\shortintertext{FFNN zwei:}
 w &= (180*h_1)+(h_1*h_2)+(h_2*13) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_ffnn_2} \\
\shortintertext{RNN eins:}
w &= (9*h_1 + h_1^2)+(h_1*13) & b &= h_1 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_1} \\
\shortintertext{RNN zwei:}
 w &= (9*h_1+h_1^2+h_1)+(h_1*h_2+h_2^2+h_2)+(h_2*13) & b &= h_1 + h_2 + 13 \label{eqn:w_rnn_2}
\end{align}}

\end{document}
```